# Is it possible to declare custom XML-elements with unqualified name?

Tags: android, android-xml

I have several custom View elements in a library with a fully qualified name like `com.company.library.customviews.CustomTextView`

It's a bit tiresome to declare xmls without autocomplete having to copy-paste the package and then manually write the classes. Makes me wanna use standard android elements that i can CTRL-SPACE within seconds.

So is there a possibility to declare them unqualified ?!

(i might not even need custom attrs, if its possible without)

**EDIT**

The auto-complete is not really my main concern/question, its readability

Comment: My main question is not solved with the template, not a duplicate

Comment: It is a duplicate, i don't have the link now but there is an answer that bypasses this problem extending the application class and doing some funny tricks.